# Is it possible to add an O365 group to a Sharepoint Teams Site with the REST API endpoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a specification that requires me to create a SharePoint Teams Site using WebTemplate STS#3, which creates a teams site with no group.

The spec then asks me to link an existing Office 365 Group to it.

I am creating the site using PHP CURL with the SharePoint REST API endpoint and would obviously like to use the API to link the SharePoint Site the group.

I’m being led by the spec (I have virtually no SharePoint Experience).I have no idea whether this is the best way to go forward or whether there are viable API driven alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that this is a verbose way of creating a Teams SharePoint site with groups. The better way to do it is use the MS Graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) to create a MS365 Group.

Creating a group also creates a Teams SharePoint site with one API call.

The Authorisation for the MS Graph API is very easy (and a lot less verbose than the older SharePoint API). A single call to the API results in a MS365 Group, a SharePoint Site and email provisioned.